# Which elememt does DataFrame. DropDuplicate drop

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

If I sort a dataframe in descending ortder based on a column.  And then drop the duplicates using df.dropDuplicate then which element will be removed?  The element which was smaller based on sort?

Comment: i think yes it should preserve the first and drop the second one i.e. drop the smaller values

Answer (score 0):

DropDuplicate method preserves the first Element and removing the others.

So yes , on descending sort only the largest(based on sort) will be preserved and others removed.

Comment: How can i keep the last element? i can't sort desc without specific column